# Is it possible to limit access to sites when sharing a web host?

Tags: web-hosting

Many web hosts let users have as many domains as they want under the same account; but in doing so, the various domains basically have access to each other using server side code/rootkits/etc.

Is there a way to effectively limit access between sites hosted on the same account with a web  host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web hosts offer reseller hosting which keeps each account separate.  Under cPanel, not even the reseller's primary account has access to each of their sites, they need to either log in to each account, or "transfer" into the sub account, but they would still not have access to any other account from there.

Comment: I don't think my current host offers a reseller setup (couldn't find any info on one for 1and1 anyway), but that's something to look for in my next host.